# Owl Carousel - Google Analytics tracking

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, owl-carousel

I am using an owl carousel as a one page site, and each page of content is on a full screen carousel slide.
I want to be able to track each slide as a Virtual PageView with Google Analytics - but I cannot work it out.
Below is the code for my previous and next buttons - but the problem is that users can also 'swipe' on touch devices - so i need to be able to track both - where do i start!?

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();

$(".next").click(function(){
owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
$(".prev").click(function(){
owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
})
});
```

Thanks for any help you can give!!

Answer (score 1):

Using v2 you can listen to "change.owl.carousel", like so:

```
var owl = $("#owl-example");

owl.on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    if (e.namespace && e.property.name === 'position') {
        // GA push to track slide view event //
        // e.relatedTarget.relative(e.property.value) is the slide number
        //_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '...']);*/
    }
});
```